# Shell loop not incrementing

Tags: shell, for-loop

I'm having a problem with a simple loop... and I wonder what's wrong with it.
Basically, I just want to increment a counter for each file found.

```
j=0
files=`ls path |grep "blabla"`
for i in $files ; 
do j=`expr $j + 1` echo "$j ---- $i"; 
done;
```

RESULT:

```
0 ---- blabla1
0 ---- blabla2
0 ---- blabla3
0 ---- blabla3
```

Why is my counter not incrementing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon:

```
do j=`expr $j + 1`; echo "$j ---- $i"; 
#                 ^-- this is missing from your code
```

Without the semicolon, the variable assignment (`j=...`) does not persist beyond the `echo`.